# Error on file upload and form data app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a web form app that would allow someone to fill in a form and upload a file IF NEEDED. The problem I'm currently having is that if the user doesn't submit a file it will prompt with an "unexpected error" prompt. The form does submit the data into the spreadsheet without error however.

What I need is for the app to not prompt with an error if the user doesn't upload a form.

```
// Script-as-app template.
var submissionSSKey = '0Aud1xlxCWoZydGllMDNwTEVhS3RqSlUyZXBwQVZTcXc';

function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Loan Registration Processing');
  var panel = app.createFormPanel();
  var grid = app.createGrid(5,2).setId('loanGrid');
  var nameLabel = app.createLabel('Name:');
  var nameTextBox = app.createTextBox().setName('name').setWidth('150px').setName('name').setId('name');

  var depLabel = app.createLabel("Department:");
  var depSelec = app.createListBox().setWidth('130px').setName('department').setId('department');
  depSelec.addItem('Select Option');
  depSelec.addItem('Cashier');
  depSelec.addItem('Text Books');
  depSelec.addItem('Greeter');
  depSelec.addItem('Runner');
  depSelec.addItem('Line Control');
  depSelec.addItem('IDB');

  var messageLabel = app.createLabel('Message:');
  var messageTextBox = app.createTextArea().setWidth('300px').setHeight('150px').setName('message').setId('message');



  var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('<B>Submit</B>'); 
  //var warning = app.createHTML('<B>PLEASE WAIT WHILE DATA IS UPLOADING<B>').setStyleAttribute('background','yellow').setVisible(false)

  //file upload
  var upLoadTypeLabel = app.createLabel('Upload Schedule:');
  var upLoad = (app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));

  //Grid layout of items on form
  grid.setWidget(0, 0, nameLabel)
  .setWidget(0, 1, nameTextBox)
  .setWidget(1, 0, depLabel)
  .setWidget(1, 1, depSelec)
  .setWidget(2, 0, messageLabel)
  .setWidget(2, 1, messageTextBox)
  .setWidget(3, 0, upLoadTypeLabel)
  .setWidget(3, 1, upLoad)
  .setWidget(4, 0, submitButton)
  //.setWidget(4, 1, warning)

  var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler();
  submitButton.addClickHandler(cliHandler);  
  panel.add(grid);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;

}

 function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var comp = 'N/A'
  var LoanType = e.parameter.name;
  var borrower = e.parameter.department;
  var amount = e.parameter.message;
  //app.getElementById('info').setVisible(true).setStyleAttribute('color','red');

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 4).setValues([[comp,LoanType,borrower,amount,]]);
   // data returned is a blob for FileUpload widget


   var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
   var doc = DocsList.getFolderById('0B-d1xlxCWoZybk1oUXhLZV91SDQ').createFile(fileBlob)
                                                              .rename(borrower+' - '+LoanType);




   return app;
 }
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because UiApp has been deprecated. Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/54605042/1595451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm not sure if you can upload a file using a normal handler. I think you have to do a POST request to upload a file. [See here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/file-upload) for an example.

That aside, you should check if a file has been uploaded and only then create the file in drive.

```
var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
if (fileBlob != null && fileBlob != undefined && fileBlob != '' ){
   var doc = DocsList.getFolderById('0B-d1xlxCWoZybk1oUXhLZV91SDQ').createFile(fileBlob).rename(borrower+' - '+LoanType);
}
```